# I'd like to extract only some first characters from a response body; curl

Tags: php, string, curl, text

well, if you're confused so am i, so to make it better for you to understand what i'd like to do this is what i think

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://google.com/a-good-coffee');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
//sleep(6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'blablabla123abc');
echo $func = curl_exec($ch);
```

let's say $func will return this
`{ "id": "great_coffee", "object": "amazing", "billing_details": google }`
what i do want to achieve is this
i want $func only to read the text in the second `" "` which is "great_coffee", the result will randomize each time i curl the same page (***lets say it's gonna be a_good_life next time i curl***)
so i dont want to get a specific value, ?
*Is this possible ? and how could i do it if it is ?

***Thank you for your responses, but if i use json_decode i will get the id yes, but i will still get some blank lines***

Comment: Why wouldn't you just decode the json and extract the `id` value? I don't get why the circuitous route to an otherwise very direct thing.

Comment: but if i use json_decode i will get the id yes, but i will still get some blank lines

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "blank lines" here. You will get a native PHP object from decoding the json.

Comment: just a lot of spacing ( around 2 lines )

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "a lot of spacing". It does exactly what you want. Beyond that I'm at a loss for how else to help you.

Comment: and i'm very thankful for helping me on that part. also this is the result i get, maybe you have some ideas?
`moonandstars    ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎                                                                                                                         `

Comment: Could you maybe be looking for the [trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) PHP function?

Comment: i tried trimming then str replace

Comment: Can you post an example of the string you're referring to with extra blank lines?

Comment: this string `moonandstars ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎           `and imagine the little blank that i added being a lot of spacing(2 lines aprox.)`

Comment: **[You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the first thing you'd want to do is decode the result into an array using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) Then you can get the array values only by using the [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function. From there you just need to get the second index.

Comment: but if i use json_decode i will get the id yes, but i will still get some blank lines